# Error (use-package): lsp-latex/:catch: Invalid version syntax: ‘command not found: texlab’ (must start with a number)

Tags: lsp-mode

I've encountered this error message when attempting to export an org file with source R code blocks.

Initially the error was..

```
Warning (emacs): Texlab executable is not found. Set ‘lsp-latex-texlab-executable’ and run ‘lsp-latex-setup-variables’ again.
```

...and I'd recently updated my system to rust-1.5.7 so duly reinstalled texlab and modified my `exec-path` to include it...

```
(setq exec-path (append '("~/bin"
                          "~/.local/bin"
                          "~/.cargo/bin/")
                         exec-path))
```

Checking the value of `exec-path` (`C-h v exec-path`) shows these are included...

```
exec-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is
("~/bin" "~/.local/bin" "~/.cargo/bin/" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/bin" "/opt/bin" "/usr/lib/llvm/13/bin" "/usr/lib/llvm/11/bin" "/usr/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
Original value was 
("/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/bin" "/opt/bin" "/usr/lib/llvm/13/bin" "/usr/lib/llvm/11/bin" "/usr/libexec/emacs/27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
```

...and `texlab` can be found under `~/.cargo/bin/` as the following shows...

```
which texlab
/home/<user>/.cargo/bin/texlab
```

I have the following to load `lsp-latex` mode

```
(use-package lsp-latex
  :ensure t
  :hook (text-mode . (lambda ()
                       (require 'lsp-latex)
                       (lsp))))
```

...but evaluating it and trying to compile my org-file to HTML both result in...

```
Error (use-package): lsp-latex/:catch: Invalid version syntax: ‘command not found: texlab’ (must start with a number)
```

I also get the following from polymode when opening my `.org` file because of the embedded R source blocks (it doesn't occur opening a pure `.org` file)...

```
Polymode error (pm--mode-setup ’org-mode): Invalid version syntax: ‘command not found: texlab’ (must start with a number)
```

...which makes me think its something fairly high level.

I found [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62678/nov-mode-returns-binary-buffer-and-file-mode-specification-error-error-invali) where someone had similar issues with the org-version not being returned but I have a valid org version (`C-h v org-version`)...

```
org-version is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is "9.4.6"
```

I can not work out where I've gone wrong nor what to investigate further, any suggestions/pointers welcome (Emacs is 27.2).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Evaluate `(executable-find "texlab")`.  Should return the full path of `texlab` otherwise emacs cannot find it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get anything returned by `(executable-find "texlab")` there is simply no output at all either saying where it is, or that it can not be found in either `*Warnings*` nor `*Messages*` or the Minibuffer. Checking `texlab -V` at the command line returns `texlab 3.3.1` so perhaps there is an issue in how this is parsed and the version is not extracted?

Comment: This is telling you that emacs is not finding `texlab` at all, your changes to `exec-path` notwithstanding.

Comment: It is indeed, I've done some investigation as this is running as emacs server, so I tried starting a new instance as user and this problem doesn't occur (although I now have other issues trying to process my org file whereby a previously working code block is not finding the org-table that preceeds it so there is something askew somewhere!).

Comment: Weird thing is it all worked fine until yesterday. I do update packages regularly from MELPA so perhaps its some package update that has broken things. Quite frustrating really.

Comment: Fudged a fix by installing `texlab` system wide (I use Gentoo and found an ebuild in an [overlay](https://gitlab.com/yemou/moulay)).